# Comparing two images visually

Tags: vb.net, computer-vision

I am wanting to be able to check to see if two images appear to be the same, within a certain threshold.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

These two images are the same to the eye, but one has slightly different colors.  I have tried the following example:

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_compare_threshold.html

Unfortunately, it only seems to detect when the images are identical.  How can I determine if the images are the same within a certain threshold, with VB.NET?

Comment: Couldn't you just display the image, recapture it and then use the code you have?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain that?

Comment: Have you used TinEye.com? They also have an API: http://ideeinc.com/products/pixmatch/  - I'm didn't see info on its tolerence but I'm sure there would be many other 3rd party tools that are similar, HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Resize both images to the same, small size, such as 16x12 or 90x60 (depending on your threshold).
2. Reduce the color depth to 4 or 8 bits per pixel (not palettized). You might use a posterize function for this.

Then then see if the two smaller images are duplicates. If so, the originals must be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

- Divide image into R, G, B
- For each color:

  - For each (x, y):

    - Multiply the pixel of Image 1 with the pixel of Image 2
  - Sum all the pixel values
- Sum the 3 values for each color

This is the [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) between the two images.  To get a value from 0 to 1, first calculate the correlation of an image with itself to see what the best possible value is, then do the correlation of Image 1 with Image 2 and divide by the best possible value.