# Compare Panel BackGround Image with Resource Image

Tags: vb.net, image, panel

I'm trying to check if my panel0.background image is the same with my image from resource then add some string to an arraylist.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
If (Panel0.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.Dinoback) Or (Panel0.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.Dinoback2) Then
        Form1.jenisbuddyarr.Add("dino")
    ElseIf (Panel0.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.Rabbitback) Or (Panel0.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.Rabbitback2) Then
        Form1.jenisbuddyarr.Add("rabbit")
    ElseIf (Panel0.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.Squirrelback) Or (Panel0.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.Squirrelback2) Then
        Form1.jenisbuddyarr.Add("squirrel")
    End If
```

Comment: Right, this won't work because every time you use My.Resources.Foo in your code, you will get a *new* image object.  You'll need to add variables of type Image in your form and assign them just once in the form constructor.  Or keep track what's in the panel with a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your current code will check if they are from same object (which is not the case). Check this thread: [Comparing two images visually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381033/comparing-two-images-visually)

```
Public Function AreSameImage(ByVal I1 As Image, ByVal I2 As Image) As Boolean
    Dim MS1 As New MemoryStream
    Dim MS2 As New MemoryStream
    I1.Save(MS1, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    I2.Save(MS2, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    For I As Integer = 0 To CInt(MS1.Length) - 1
      If MS1.ReadByte() <> MS2.ReadByte Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function

If (AreSameImage(Panel0.BackgroundImage, My.Resources.Dinoback)) '...
```